# Problemas con ScrollView Android

Tags: android-studio, scroll-view

tengo un problema con el contenedor ScrollView. Pasa que cuando la implementé la pantalla se me pone demasiado larga, es decir, el height es como si "no tuviese" fin. Adjunto pieza del código y una foto.

```
    <ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/mainContainer"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">
    <LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/linearLayoutMain"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">
```

[image: imagen de la vista gráfica]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cambia la definición de la altura del contenedor principal que es tu `ScrollView` a `"wrap_content"` :

```
 <ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/mainContainer"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"

    android:layout_height="wrap_content"

    tools:context=".MainActivity">
```

Comment: Muchas gracias! Me ayudó.

Comment: Excelente, @Ethernal saludos!